getline advances to next file instead of returning EOF
getline is specified to read "from the current input file" and to return 0 at the end-of-file. Both gawk and POSIX docs use this verbiage. It makes sense: Data may be divided between files for a reason. The language is more expressive if getline can distinguish files. Information that is structured enough to warrant getline usually doesn't cross file boundaries.
But both GNU and macOS/BSD implementations hide the EOF and immediately open the next file. Doing so, they update FILENAME, which is not among the list of variables specified to be affected in either GNU nor POSIX docs.
The only workaround I see is to make sure that each file starts with a throwaway line, and detect when FNR resets to 1. Yuck.
It's a strange coincidence for both implementations to have this bug. Looking at the source, neither behavior is negligent. Both take specific steps to advance the file, in contrast to the code branch for getline from a named I/O handle. It's especially weird for the verbose GNU docs to contradict the behavior.
Am I missing something? Have I stumbled across an uncommon case or is this known to Awk lore?

You've got it. Your key with multiple input files is to use FNR and/or FILENAME in a conditional. The input seen by awk with multiple filenames specified is just the total NR to process. There is no EOF thrown when file1 is complete and awk starts reading file2, etc... No different than having done cat file1 file2 ... | awk '{...}' (other than the benefit of having FNR and FILENAME available for use). Think of it this way, awk processes records (lines), the fact your have FNR and FILENAME is a side-effect of specifying separate filenames.

@DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the insider perspective. Is that anywhere in the docs? I thought I read them thoroughly. Saying "current input file" throws me off. Why not say "the next record" like everywhere else.

You should read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline once the site becomes available again.

I read it on archive.org, thanks. Still such a strange situation. What kind of program would depend on this behavior? The philosophy makes sense in that it’s self-consistent, but it’s disadvantageous… and somehow the docs and standards agree with each other in some wishful thinking instead of following reality.

open-source is an interesting mix, and documentation is always written last, by the person drawing the black-bean... I've always just rationalized the behavior of awk from the records standpoint. While it is a step up from the stream editor approach of sed, it certainly wasn't written around input exclusively from getline. I've never thought about the EOF behavior from getline that closely, but from the user's standpoint the actual low-level I/O of the input files is handled by awk at a level that isn't directly exposed to the user -- so the absence of EOF sort of makes sense.

@EdMorton If you wouldn’t mind copying some of that post here to make an answer, it would help make the content more accessible and we could close this question.

@DavidC.Rankin I suppose the documentation authors, and ultimately the POSIX committee, just copied and embellished prior docs. The problem I see is that getline is too greedy, making it hard to leave in case it’s getting used in a special case, not as the main input mode. Anyhow the better (or conceptually consistent) way is to add variables to keep track of grammatical state globally, not to attempt to write a bottom-up parser.

@Potatoswatter : just wanna quickly chime in - why do you consider getline the "main input mode" for awk ? To me it seems more an auxiliary facility.

@Potatoswatter : You had the opinion that a pattern detecting FNR == 1 is a "throwaway line". Just curious, even if non-gawk variants of awk had a built-in pattern for EOF, wouldn't that be just as "throwaway", since the pattern would also only get invoked once per file, just like FNR == 1 ?

If you're …. ahem …… seeking a language with plenty of syntactical sugars to minimize "throwaway lines", perhaps the great Larry Wall success story that is Raku ?

You say "The only workaround I see is to make sure that each file starts with a throwaway line, and detect when FNR resets to 1" but ... workaround for what? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with 2 or 3 small input files showing what the specific problem is with the existing functionalitys behavior that you're trying to find a workaround for.

@RAREKpopManifesto No, I was replying to David's point about "input exclusively from getline". The problem with FNR == 1 is that it tells you that the first line of the next file has already been consumed and it's too late to send it back to the main rules of the program.

@EdMorton Sorry, I was just assuming that the common use of getline is to treat a few consecutive lines specially in a loop instead of pattern-matching. If a file ends unexpectedly, it would be more elegant to exit the loop before entering the next file, so the next can be correctly processed. My use case, for what it's worth, is fairly contrived. I'm writing a toy database server. It opens and re-opens a pipe per client connection. When I tried to getline up to EOF in case of garbage input, the loop never exited. But there are plenty of other approaches.

Please [edit] your question to contain all relevant information including a [mcve]. Don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed. Not my downvote by the way.

It sounds like you just want a want a way to know when a getline loop reaches end of file so here is a way to do that.
Using these input files which includes 1 empty file (not impossible to handle in any awk but significantly harder to handle without ENDFILE because getline won't return between attempting to read that empty file and reading the first line of the next file and ARGV[] could contain variable assignments intermingled with file names and could contain multiple occurrences of the same file name):
$ head file{1..3}
==> file1 <==
foo
bar

==> file2 <==

==> file3 <==
some
other
stuff

With GNU awk you could do:
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        while ( getline > 0 ) {
            print FILENAME, $0
        }
    }
    ENDFILE {
        print "Finished reading", FILENAME
    }
' file{1..3}
file1 foo
file1 bar
Finished reading file1
Finished reading file2
file3 some
file3 other
file3 stuff
Finished reading file3

but without a concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve, I don't know if that would be a solution to it or not.
By the way...

The docs should say "end of input" instead of "end of file". You could open a bug report with the gawk providers for that if you like, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bug-address, and/or the POSIX people, see http://www.opengroup.org/austin/.

You say in the question:

Doing so, they update FILENAME, which is not among the list of
variables specified to be affected in either GNU nor POSIX docs.

but the GNU awk manual says the following in the Points to Remember About getline section:

It is worth noting that those variants that do not use redirection can
cause FILENAME to be updated if they cause awk to start reading a new
input file.

That is made explicit in the table of impacted variables in the AllAboutGetline* article though.


*AllAboutGetline
Make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline (if that site is down see the archive at https://web.archive.org/web/20221109201352/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) if you're ever considering using getline.

Thanks! This wasn't a how-to question. Since it's definitely intentional divergence, perhaps I'll submit a GNU documentation correction and an Open Group defect report.
